# Opengl/glsl/lwjgl either 2d or 3d, not both?

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

So I'm trying to render a basic overlay onto my 3D scene, and currently I can either have the 3D scene or the 2D overlay, I cant work out how to get both

In my main method, where render is called, I moved specific render functions to manager classes, so in the main render I call :

```
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();       
        
        glOrtho(-aspect, aspect, -1, 1, -10, 10);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        material.setColour(new Vector3f(1,1,1));            
        sLight.getPointLight().setPosition(camera.getPosition());
        sLight.setDirection(camera.getForward());
        
        DayCycle.getInstance().update(Time.getDelta());
        
        shader.updateUniforms(transform.getTransformation(), transform.getProjectedTransformation(), material); 
        //material is a wrapper class for textures and specular value etc
        //transform is a matrix wrapper for getting projected transformations, taking the camera position when its created
        WorldManager.renderAll(true); //true denotes yes to wireframe mode
        
        InterfaceManager.renderAll();
        
        glfwSwapBuffers(window); 
        glfwPollEvents();
```

If i comment out WorldManager.renderAll(), I get the little 2d square in the right part of the screen, If i dont comment it, I get the world render but no little square

WorldManager.renderAll()

```
    public static void renderAll(boolean wireframeMode)
    {
    RendererUtils.setWireframeMode(wireframeMode);
    
    for (String s : chunks.keySet())
    {
        Chunk actingChunk = chunks.get(s);
        
        Transform transform = new Transform();
        Shader shader = PhongShader.getInstance();
        transform.setTranslation(new Vector3f(actingChunk.getLocation().getX() * (Chunk.ChunkSize),0.0f, actingChunk.getLocation().getY() * (Chunk.ChunkSize)));
        transform.setScale(1.0f, 50f, 1.0f);
        shader.updateUniforms(transform.getTransformation(), transform.getProjectedTransformation(), actingChunk.getMaterial());
        shader.bind();
        
        actingChunk.getMesh().draw();
        //transform.setRotation(new Vector3f(0,0,0));
    }
    }
```

InterfaceManager.renderAll()

```
    public static void renderAll()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -10, 10);
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    RendererUtils.setWireframeMode(false);
    for (Interface i : interfaces)
    {
        Transform transform = new Transform();
        transform.setTranslation(new Vector3f(0,0,0));
        InterfaceShader.getInstance().updateUniforms(transform.getProjectedTransformation());
        InterfaceShader.getInstance().bind();
        
        i.getMesh().draw();
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

When I have WorldManager.renderAll() uncommented, i get a nice sea of triangles (as its meant to look) but no 2D square [image: 3D]
With it commented, I get a nice little square where its meant to be and nothing else [image: 2D square!]

Shaders are here : https://pastebin.com/xWaWhQHy because I felt this post was getting too long to have them inlined

What's my problem? I cant figure out where it is

Edit : If i've missed any pertinent code, tell me and i'll upload it to a pastebin

Edit 2 : updated my code here to reflect that i'd removed a shader in interfaceManager to actually get a square to draw at all : https://pastebin.com/pHHDsCvF for the shader code

Edit 3 : Ive determined it's something to do with my interface shaders, If i use PhongShader instead of InterfaceShader then it works exactly how I wanted it to

Comment: If you draw worldmanager you bind a shader, you don't bind a shader in the code you showed from InterfaceManager, so I assume that you want a different shader there?

Comment: Er, yes good catch, I had a shader in there but it produced a black screen so i cut it out
When it was still in there, it meant that interfaceManager didnt draw anything regardless of whether worldManager.draw was commented or not

Should I add in the cut code and add my InterfaceShader to a pastebin too?

Comment: I'm trying to tell you that if you don't use `glUseProgram(0);` then the worldmanager shader is still active when you draw with interfacemanager

Comment: Yeah, i get that, but unbinding the shader doesnt seem to make a difference, strangely

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to modify the code this way:

```
  WorldManager.renderAll(true); //true denotes yes to wireframe mode

  glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  InterfaceManager.renderAll();
```

This way you will clear depth buffer before rendering 2d interface.

Comment: either that or just `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`, should be faster than clearing depth buffer twice per frame

Comment: I already do that in the InterfaceManager render method, disable depth test i mean

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was still applying transformations to the vertices after passing them to the shader.

By editing out the transformation (and later scrapping the entire vertex shader) in the InterfaceShader instance, the little squares were appearing in the right place